# Keep properties after spatial join

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, export, spatial-join

I have two Feature collections: One that includes the location of dams and one that provides the basin area of a river within a country. I want to use gee to obtain a list of dams constructed in a basin area (I don't need dams outside of basin areas). In the end I want to have a table that includes all properties of the dam feature collection and add the name of the country ("CCODE") and the name of the river basin ("BCODE") from the basin dataset.
I used a spatial join. But when I export the data I loose the information on the basin dataset (I guess it should be in 'scenes'). This is my code:

```
//Load dams
var GrandDams = ee.FeatureCollection('users/basins/GRanD_dams_v1_3');

//load basins
var BCU = ee.FeatureCollection('users/basins/TFDD_BCU');

var spatialFilter = ee.Filter.intersects({
  leftField: '.geo',
  rightField: '.geo',
  maxError: 10
});

var saveAllJoin = ee.Join.saveAll({
  matchesKey: 'scenes',
});

var BCU_dams = saveAllJoin.apply(GrandDams, BCU, spatialFilter);

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: BCU_dams,
  description: 'Dams',
  fileFormat: 'CSV',
});
```

How can I add the country and basin name from the basin dataset to the exported table?